# How to structure and search Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I'm building a Rails app with two models Users & Documents. A user can have 1,000s of documents.

I'm looking for advice on how to set this up with Rails and Elasticsearch. Should I use an index per each user in Elasticsearch?

Also, right now when I perform Document.search, it is returning @documents results for all users. What is the right way to limit search results to the particular Document.user_id. I'm guessing these two questions are related which is why I included them in one question.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Down votes can signify someone believing you haven't done enough research. There are many hits when searching for "rails elasticsearch". Have you read those? Have you tried their solutions? If so, then ask a specific question about the problem, not a general, broad, question. "[mcve]" will help you frame that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you were going to have a very small number of users with a very large (100s of thousands and more) you almost definitely don't want an index per user. There is a per index overhead which would become significant with large numbers of users.

One possible exception might be if different users were going to store documents with very different fields, but even then you'd be better off with a small number of indices rather than one per user.